# Calculate monthly mean from daily data for each year

Tags: python, group-by, mean, python-xarray, resampling

I have seen many answers how to calculate the monthly mean from daily data across multiple years.

But what I want to do is to calculate the monthly mean from daily data for each year in my xarray separately. So, I want to end up with a mean for Jan 2020, Feb 2020 ... Dec 2024 for each lon/lat gridpoint.

My xarray has the dimensions Frozen({'time': 1827, 'lon': 180, 'lat': 90})
I tried using
`var_resampled = var_diff.resample(time='1M').mean()`
but this calcualtes the mean across all years (ie mean for Jan 2020-2024).

I also tried

```
    def mon_mean(x):
        return x.groupby('time.month').mean('time')

    # group by year, then apply the function:
    var_diff_mon = var_diff.groupby('time.year').apply(mon_mean)
```

This seems to do what I want but I end up with different dimensions (ie "month" and "year" instead of the original "time" dimension).

Is there a different way to calculate the monthly mean from daily data for each year separately or is there a way that the code using groupby above retains the same time dimension as before just with year and month now?

P.S. I also tried "cdo monmean" but as far as I understand this also just gives mean the monthly mean across all years.

Thanks!

**Solution**
I found a way using

```
    def mon_mean(x):
        return x.groupby('time.month').mean('time')

    # group by year, then apply the function:
    var_diff_mon = var_diff.groupby('time.year').apply(mon_mean)
```

and then using

```
var_diff_mon.stack(time=("year", "month"))
```

to get my original time dimension back

Comment: 'I also tried "cdo monmean" but as far as I understand this also just gives mean the monthly mean across all years.' This seems incorrect. `monmean` should do exactly what you want. If it's not, there is likely something going wrong with the netCDF files you are working with.

Comment: @RobertWilson Ok I will try that again. From the data structure I had the feeling that monmean just calculated the monthly mean across all years.

Answer (score 4):

Is `var_diff.resample(time='M')` (or `time='MS'`) doing what you expect ?

Let's create a toy dataset like yours:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

dims = ('time', 'lat', 'lon')
time = pd.date_range("2021-01-01T00", "2023-12-31T23", freq="H")
lat = [0, 1]
lon = [0, 1]
coords = (time, lat, lon)

ds = xr.DataArray(data=np.random.randn(len(time), len(lat), len(lon)), coords=coords, dims=dims).rename("my_var")
ds = ds.to_dataset()
ds
```

[image: toy_ds]

Let's resample it:

```
ds.resample(time="MS").mean()
```

[image: toy_ds_resampled]

The dataset has now 36 time steps, associated with the 36 months which are in the original dataset.

Comment: Hi there, the issue that it resamples for month across all years and I only need to resample for each month for each year separately

Comment: Did you try these lines ? ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do not know what I did wrong when I tried it but this seems to work:)